# jQuery causes page to break in IE7, Works fine in all other browsers

Tags: jquery, wordpress, internet-explorer-7, conflict

I'm working on a site and we're ready to go live. Until I started doing IE edits. The page is broken in IE7 because of my jQuery. It is a wordpress platform with multiple plugins, but I have disabled plugins one at a time with no success. I put the jQuery in no conflict mode with still no success. Any help would be much appreciated. I've included my jQuery below, the url for the site is http://prospermodels.com. If you wouldn't mind helping me I can get you admin access, etc. Thanks again.

/***JQUERY CODE BELOW**/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".heat").after("<div class='heatD' style='display: none;'>Heat Description which is available in the jQuery in the footer.</div>");
    jQuery('.heat').hover(function() {
        jQuery('.heatD').show();
        jQuery(".heatD").css("margin-bottom", 300);
        }, function() {
            jQuery('.heatD').hide();
        });
    jQuery(".cold").after("<div class='coldD' style='display: none;'>Heat Description which is available in the jQuery in the footer.</div>");
    jQuery('.cold').hover(function() {
        jQuery('.coldD').show();
        jQuery(".coldD").css("margin-bottom", 300);
    }, function() {
        jQuery('.coldD').hide();
    });
    jQuery(function(jQuery) {
        var slide = false;
        var height = jQuery('#wordd').height();
        jQuery('#footer_button').click(function() {
            var docHeight = jQuery(document).height();
            var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();
            var scrollPos = docHeight - windowHeight + height;
            jQuery('#wordd').animate({ height: "toggle"}, 400);
            if(slide == false) {
                if(jQuery.browser.opera) { //Fix opera double scroll bug by targeting only HTML.
                    jQuery('html').animate({scrollTop: scrollPos+'px'}, 400);
                } else {
                    jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: scrollPos+'px'}, 400);
                }
                slide = true;
            } else {
                slide = false;
            }
        });

    });
    jQuery(function(){
        var footerHeight = jQuery("#foot").height();
        var footerHeight2 = footerHeight + 40;
        var moree = footerHeight / 4;
        var mentrymore = footerHeight / 2;
        jQuery("#wrapper").css("margin-bottom", -moree);
    });
    jQuery("#right").stickyfloat({lockBottom: false, startOffset: 180});
    var i = 0;
    jQuery('.alignleft').each(function() {
        var me = this;
        jQuery(this).hide()
        var j = i;
        setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery(me).fadeIn(1000);
        }, i)
        i += 100
    });
    if ((jQuery("#formBuilderContact").css("display")) == "none") {
        jQuery("#formBuilderContact").css({display:"none"});
        jQuery("#formula1").click(function() {
        jQuery("#formBuilderContact").fadeIn();
        jQuery("#formula1").css({display:"none"});
        });
    }
    (function(jQuery) {
        jQuery.fn.customFadeIn = function(speed, callback) {
            jQuery(this).fadeIn(speed, function() {
            if(jQuery.browser.msie)
                jQuery(this).get(0).style.removeAttribute('filter');
            if(callback != undefined)
                callback();
            });
        };
        jQuery.fn.customFadeOut = function(speed, callback) {
            jQuery(this).fadeOut(speed, function() {
            if(jQuery.browser.msie)
                jQuery(this).get(0).style.removeAttribute('filter');
            if(callback != undefined)
                callback();
            });
        };
    })(jQuery);
    if(!jQuery.browser.msie){ // IE  - 2nd level Fix
        jQuery("ul.topnav").css({opacity:"0.95"});
    }
    jQuery(".nav > li > ul").css({display: "none"});
    jQuery(".nav > li > ul > li > ul").css({display: "block"});// Opera Fix
    jQuery("ul.nav li.current_page_ancestor ul.children").css({display: "block"});
    jQuery("ul.children").parent().append("<span></span>"); //Only shows drop down trigger when js is enabled - Adds empty span tag after ul.subnav
    jQuery("ul.nav li a").hover(function() { 
        var plug = jQuery(this).parent().find("ul.children");
        plug.customFadeIn();
        jQuery(this).parent().hover(function() {

        }, function(){
            jQuery(this).parent().find("ul.children").customFadeOut(200); //When the mouse hovers out of the subnav, move it back up
        });
        //Following events are applied to the trigger (Hover events for the trigger)
        }).hover(function() {
            jQuery(this).addClass("subhover"); //On hover over, add class "subhover"
        }, function(){  //On Hover Out
            jQuery(this).removeClass("subhover"); //On hover out, remove class "subhover"
    });
    if(!(jQuery.browser.msie)) {                        
        jQuery('div.grow').divgrow({ initialHeight: 75, moreText: "+ read more", lessText: "- show less", showBrackets: false});
    }
    else {
        jQuery('div.grow').divgrow({ initialHeight: 85, moreText: "+ read more", lessText: "- show less", showBrackets: false});
    }
    if(!(jQuery.browser.msie)) {                        
        jQuery('div.grow2').divgrow({ initialHeight: 83, moreText: "+ read more", lessText: "- show less", showBrackets: false});
    }
    else {
        jQuery('div.grow2').divgrow({ initialHeight: 88, moreText: "+ read more", lessText: "- show less", showBrackets: false});
    }
    function slideSwitch() {
        var active = jQuery('#slideshow IMG.active');
        if ( active.length == 0 ) active = jQuery('#slideshow IMG:last');
        var next =  active.next().length ? active.next()
        : jQuery('#slideshow IMG:first');
        active.addClass('last-active');
        next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
        textSwitch();
    }
    var totPics = "<?= $totPics ?>";
    var activeDiv = 2;
    var text1 = "<?= $text1 ?>";
    var text2 = "<?= $text2 ?>";
    var text3 = "<?= $text3 ?>";
    var text4 = "<?= $text4 ?>";
    function textSwitch() {
        if (activeDiv <= totPics) {
            if (activeDiv == 1) {
                jQuery('#div<? echo $totPics ?>').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                jQuery('#div1').css({display: 'inline-block'})
                jQuery("#div1").fadeIn("slow");
            });
            activeDiv++;
            }
            else if (activeDiv == 2) {
                jQuery('#div1').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    jQuery('#div2').css({display: 'inline-block'})
                    jQuery("#div2").fadeIn("slow");
                });
                activeDiv++;
            }
            else if (activeDiv == 3) {
                jQuery('#div2').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    jQuery('#div3').css({display: 'inline-block'})
                    jQuery("#div3").fadeIn("slow");
                });
                activeDiv++;
            }
            else if (activeDiv == 4) {
                jQuery('#div3').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    jQuery('#div4').css({display: 'inline-block'})
                    jQuery("#div4").fadeIn("slow");
                });
                activeDiv = 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            activeDiv = 1;
            textSwitch();
        }
    }
    jQuery(function() {
        if (totPics > 0) {    
            setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
        }
    });
    /*HOVER INTENT COPY AND PASTED */
    (function($){$.fn.hoverIntent=function(f,g){var cfg={sensitivity:7,interval:100,timeout:0};cfg=$.extend(cfg,g?{over:f,out:g}:f);var cX,cY,pX,pY;var track=function(ev){cX=ev.pageX;cY=ev.pageY;};var compare=function(ev,ob){ob.hoverIntent_t=clearTimeout(ob.hoverIntent_t);if((Math.abs(pX-cX)+Math.abs(pY-cY))<cfg.sensitivity){$(ob).unbind("mousemove",track);ob.hoverIntent_s=1;return cfg.over.apply(ob,[ev]);}else{pX=cX;pY=cY;ob.hoverIntent_t=setTimeout(function(){compare(ev,ob);},cfg.interval);}};var delay=function(ev,ob){ob.hoverIntent_t=clearTimeout(ob.hoverIntent_t);ob.hoverIntent_s=0;return cfg.out.apply(ob,[ev]);};var handleHover=function(e){var p=(e.type=="mouseover"?e.fromElement:e.toElement)||e.relatedTarget;while(p&&p!=this){try{p=p.parentNode;}catch(e){p=this;}}if(p==this){return false;}var ev=jQuery.extend({},e);var ob=this;if(ob.hoverIntent_t){ob.hoverIntent_t=clearTimeout(ob.hoverIntent_t);}if(e.type=="mouseover"){pX=ev.pageX;pY=ev.pageY;$(ob).bind("mousemove",track);if(ob.hoverIntent_s!=1){ob.hoverIntent_t=setTimeout(function(){compare(ev,ob);},cfg.interval);}}else{$(ob).unbind("mousemove",track);if(ob.hoverIntent_s==1){ob.hoverIntent_t=setTimeout(function(){delay(ev,ob);},cfg.timeout);}}};return this.mouseover(handleHover).mouseout(handleHover);};})(jQuery);

});
```

Comment: What is broken? Do you get errors? Going to need more info..

Comment: Open || download the f12 dev-tools and see if u get errors.

Comment: The page displays, but none of the jquery actually works. The nav is controlled by jquery, and it shows ALL the links instead of showing just subpages of the current page, as well as a popup footer which doesn't actually popup on click.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be erros in the error console, which is what confuses me. And it's solely in IE7, all other browsers work fine. Does the version of jquery matter? Is it possible ie7 doesn't support recent versions of jquery?

Comment: I would take a guess that it is not broken jquery rather broken dom rendering. IE7 is renowned for terrible handling of anything complex in its render. Consider IE7 the next IE6...

Answer (score 0):

I have a website where JQuery fails to work in IE7. There's nothing wrong with your code, and there's nothing you can do rectify this, unless you was to get someone else to create the same code that you did, so they would do it in a different way.